# Cocoa giving error: <Error>: doClip: empty path

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, console

Cocoa gives error:

```
Thu Jun 10 19:13:56 myComputer.local myApp[####] <Error>: doClip: empty path.
```

But I don't have this function anywhere in my code (can't find by searching in frameworks / project)... Seems a lot of people complain about this because it goes into the console logs, but couldn't find any reason given as to what causes it on a progmatic level.

Any thoughts as to what the problem is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Poking around with class-dump and nm, I found that it's a function in CoreGraphics (Quartz 2D). It's not declared in the headers, so it's a private function.

Break on `doClip` in the debugger, then move down the stack and see whether any of your code is drawing at that time. If so, you're probably trying to clip to an empty path. If a third-party framework you're using is involved, you should file a bug with its authors.

If you're not calling it (and you shouldn't), and a third-party framework is not implicated, it's probably a bug in one of the Apple frameworks. You should [report it to Apple](https://bugreport.apple.com/).

Comment: Not breaking on doClip... am I typing it wrong? http://i259.photobucket.com/albums/hh299/PirateOrion/Screenshot2010-06-11at122913PM.png

Comment: You're doing it right, but look at the checkbox: The breakpoint isn't bound. Try linking against ApplicationServices; if that doesn't help, my guess would be that the function is `static` and so can't be named in a breakpoint.

Comment: I've found that you can get the breakpoint to fire if you break on CGPostError.

Answer (score 9):

I would just check to see if the path is empty using:  CGContextIsPathEmpty(CGContextRef ctx)

Example:

```
if(!CGContextIsPathEmpty(c))
    CGContextClip(c);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this error before when drawing in a context and trying to clip it. Are you doing any context drawing like this?

```
CGContextClip(ctx);
CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, image.size.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.0, -1.0);
CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height), image.CGImage);
```

Comment: Nope.  It was something lower down.  But I'm afraid I've moved on :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when I implemented the following methods to set the navigation bar image override specific for landscape orientation. To get rid of the clip error I commented out the CGContextClip portion of the code as shown below:

```
@implementation UINavigationBar(CustomBackground)

+ (UIImage *) bgImagePortrait
{
    static UIImage *image = nil;
    if (image == nil) {
        image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"iPhoneHeader_portrait"] retain];
}
    return image;
}

+ (UIImage *) bgImageLandscape
{
    static UIImage *image = nil;
    if (image == nil) {
    image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"iPhoneHeader_landscape"] retain];
    }
    return image;
}

- (void) drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
{
    if ([self isMemberOfClass:[UINavigationBar class]] == NO) {
    return;
}
    UIImage *image = (self.frame.size.width > 320) ?
    [UINavigationBar bgImageLandscape] : [UINavigationBar bgImagePortrait];
    //CGContextClip(ctx); // Causes '<Error>: doClip: empty path.' error when changing views.
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, image.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height), image.CGImage);
}

@end
```